# Term for a structure of nested holding companies

Tags: phrases, legalese, finance

An example would be a corporation A, that holds a controlling interest (say 51%) in company B, which holds a controlling interest (51% again) in company C, and now company A has a controlling interest in company C while only owning 25.5% of its stock.

In Hebrew this is called a (literal translation) "control pyramid", but I can't find an equivalent term in English.

Comment: In English, "pyramid structure" (when the reference to holding companies is clear) or "pyramid shareholding structure" is the equivalent phrase, but your "control pyramid" also works, given a defining context. See, for example, ["Concentration of Ownership and Pyramidal Shareholding Structures in Belgian Listed Companies European Corporate Governance Network"](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/242183458_Concentration_of_Ownership_and_Pyramidal_Shareholding_Structures_in_Belgian_Listed_Companies_European_Corporate_Governance_Network).

Comment: Also ["Taking a pick to the last pyramid"](http://www.fin24.com/Finweek/Cover-Story/Taking-a-pick-to-the-last-pyramid-20110124), etc. The phrase is in common use.

Comment: Such **pyramidal structure** allows a holding to control its subsidiaries and the sub-subsidiaries by owning only a small percentage of shares.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to a ***[holding company structure](https://blog.udemy.com/holding-company-structure/):***

> - A holding company is a firm that owns the outstanding stock of other companies. The term usually refers to the company that does not produce or manufacture goods itself, but owns the shares of other companies that produce goods and services.
>
>   - Holding companies reduce the risk of owners and allow the ownership of multiple companies. You can turn your business into a holding company for the purpose of owning property such as patents, estates, trademarks, and other assets. There are numerous benefits of forming holding companies.

[image]

Comment: As you say *Holding Company* means one that does nothing but *hold* (a controlling interest in) other companies. The whole structure, in the UK, would be called a *Group*.

Answer (score 0):

The Internal Revenue Service (US) calls this a "controlled group."